# Regex: Do not include a substring within a group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm wondering if it is possible to exclude part of a match within a group.

I believe that `/(foo((?:bar)|(bad)))/` results in matching "foobar" or "foobad" and group 1 containing "foobar" or "foobad". I would like it to match "foobar" or "foobad" but group 1 contain only "foo" or "foobad".  I know that the `(?:...)` regex syntax is used to make a group that you cannot reference later on, but the above usage means that there are 3 groups: \1 the entire match; \2 either 'bar' or 'bad'; \NONE being an unused group 'bar'; and \3 for 'bad'.

You see where I'm going here? I want to optionally exclude a sub group from within another group.

Alternatively, I would like to define group 1 twice in an OR fashion `/(foobar)|(foobad)/` though I know that input wouldn't do what I wanted.  In that case, trying to access `match[1]` results in an "undefined" error if given "foobad" as input.  I know this is because it is actually splitting it into group 1 and or group 2.

I'm writing this in the javascript regex dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like it to match "foobar" or "foobad" but group 1 contain only "foo" or "foobad".

The regex:

```
/(foo(?:(?=bar)|bad))/
```

does that: group 1 either contains `foo` (only if `bar` comes directly after it) or it contains `foobad`.

Comment: Good answer.  For some reason I thought JS didn't support look-ahead, but it does, so that will work perfectly. (once the parens match, anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks for the correction Tim :). Yeah, JS support look-aheads, but  doesn't support look-behinds.

Comment: It should be noted that this will change the behavior of any following matches.  For example `(foo(?:(?=bar)|bad))x` will match `foobadx` but will *not* match `foobarx` at all.

Comment: @Tim, not sure if I follow you... The string `foobarx` _does_ get matched (at least the `foo` part, that is).

Comment: Ahh, lookahead was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Bart Try it yourself.  Put this in your address bar: `javascript:alert('foobarx'.match(/(foo(?:(?=bar)|bad))x/))` and you'll get `null`; change to 'foobadx' and you get a match.

Comment: Ah, you meant that if `x` gets included in the regex itself (I didn't notice that before). Yeah, then things might go wrong. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:bar)` - Matches *bar* but does not remember the match. These are called **non-capturing parentheses**. The matched substring can not be recalled from the resulting array's elements `[1], ..., [n]` or from the predefined RegExp object's properties `$1, ..., $9`.

Further info: [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp).

Comment: You missed the point, he doesn't want to capture "bar" in group 1.

Comment: `[bar|bad]` matches just one character: `b`, `a`, `r`, `|` or `d`

Comment: @BartPiers - Right, my fault, corrected it.
@TimSylvester - Didn't understand his question. Trying to figure out.

Comment: `[(?:bar)|(?:bad)]` again matches only one character, one of: `(`, `?`, `:`, `b`, `a`, `r`, `)`, `|` or `d`. Note that everything between `[` and `]` is a character set. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Am I totally nuts? You're right again... I should pay more atention to my postings...

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what you want

```
/((?=foobar)foo|foobad)/
```

it's a single group that matches either `foo` (but only if starting with that it would have matched `foobar`) or `foobad`. The form `(?=...)` is a zero-width look-ahead assertion.

It's not exactly what you want because the match in case of `foobar` is just `foo` but IMO to be able to have it to match foobar but grouping only foo in the same group where foobad would be matched instead requires lookbehind and AFAIK it's not available in javascript.